# How to call repeat fun within replace range in Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I got this code

```
val numberOfStars = urlString.length - index
val result = urlString.replaceRange(index+1..urlString.length - 1,"*") //Here
```

I need to repeat replacing of character with `"*"` by `numberOfStars`. Now it replace only once. And I have result like this `somehere=*` but I need if `numberOfStars=5` the result will be `somehere=*****`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no method out of the box .... but you can do it like

`val result = urlString.replaceRange(index+1..urlString.length - 1,"*".repeat(numberOfStars))`

Comment: thank you. ye that's what I was looking for. Did not know where to put `.repeat()`

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to replace everything from index to the end of the string, it is not really necessary to use `replaceRange`. The following is a bit less redundant, because you do not need to write the length of the `urlString` twice:

```
val numberOfStars = urlString.length - index
val result = urlString.substring(0, index + 1) + "*".repeat(numberOfStars)
```

It would also be possible to do it like this:

```
val result = urlString.mapIndexed { i, c -> if(i > index) "*" else c }
                      .joinToString(separator = "")
```